# MVC 5 Option Empty Line With JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

```
$('#DepartmentCode').change(function () {
    var empName = $('#Employee_No');
    var department = $('#DepartmentCode').val();
    empName.empty();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/LeaveRequestEntry/GetEmployeesByDept",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({ ClassCode: department }),
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, option) {
                empName.append('<option value=' + option.Value + '>' + option.Text + '</option>');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

This is my JavaScript code.

```
   ViewBag.Employee = employeeRepository.GetAllByDepartment(ClassCode).Select(e => new SelectListItem { Text = e.Full_Name + "_" + e.No, Value = e.No });
    return Json(new SelectList(ViewBag.Employee, "Value", "Text"));
```

This is my controller part.

```
    <div class="field">
        @Html.DropDownList("Department", new SelectList(ViewBag.DepartmentList, "Value", "Text"), LeaveRequestEntryRes.SelectableMessage, new { @class = "ui fluid dropdown", @id = "DepartmentCode" })
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        @Html.DropDownList("Employee_No", new SelectList(ViewBag.EmployeeList, "Value", "Text"), LeaveRequestEntryRes.SelectableMessage, new { @class = "ui fluid dropdown" })
    </div>
```

There are 2 options in the html part. When I select a department, the employees of that department come. My problem is that one of them is always selected. I want to click and select. how do i fix it so that if i click it ??
Sorry for my English. :)

Comment: What do you mean by "one of them is always selected"? I see that in your code, you are using the html.dropdownlist with overload for `optionlabel`

Comment: @JerdineSabio a `<select>` will always have an `<option>` selected - as OP is empy()ing the options first then only adding ones that match a department, they are left with the first selected.  The obvious solution is to add an empty `<option value=''></option>` before adding the department options - this will then be "selected" by default.

Comment: @freedomn-m The OP is already using the overload that adds an empty option, even using the `LeaveRequestEntryRes.SelectableMessage` as the default value. But yes what you mentioned is easiest workaround. Just curious why the default value isn't working.

Comment: @JerdineSabio only in the initial load / page render, not the ajax success: callback

Comment: @freedomn-m Ah! Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not just set a placeholder option above the loop in the success?

for example:

```
empName.append('<option value="" selected>Select an option</option>');

// The loop to populate
```